# Redefine sonar.cxx.includeDirectories without overriding it

Tags: sonarqube

I have set my system includes in the Sonarqube GUI and would like to add other includes in the project level.

Is it possible to redefine the parameter without loosing the original includes?

I tried to do a bash like redefinition:

```
sonar.cxx.includeDirectories = $sonar.cxx.includeDirectories, includes
```

But this does not seem to work.

[Edit]

So here is what I do. 
I set the global includes in Sonarqube settings

```
Settings -> C++ (Community) -> (1) General -> Include directories
```

Then I had `sonar.cxx.includeDirectories` in my .properties file

Comment: where is located the property redefinition you tried? it would help understanding how you are trying to define project level properties

Comment: @Seb-SonarSourceTeam: I have updated the question, hope this helps